# Values of numpy array change when reading them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When i try to read an element (a row) from an numpy array, it returns all values converted weirdly. In PyCharm i can see the whole array in the SciView-Window and all rows are shown perfectly normal. This only appears when i try to read rows with a high index (10,000+).

Example of how the array looks:

```
x, y, z, red, green, blue
-192.10187, -192.14468, -192.20335, -192.21474, -192.15605, -224.99792
...
-52.04092, -51.98182, -52.03537, -46.29209, -46.29368, -46.27203
```

Example of my code:

```
>>> my_array[0]
array([ -192.10187, -192.14468, -192.20335, -192.21474, -192.15605, -224.99792])

>>> my_array[10000]
array([ 1.00001000e+05, -5.20409241e+01,  1.88983292e+02,  2.47587326e+02,
        6.30000000e+01,  7.90000000e+01,  3.40000000e+01])
```

Why do my values get changed that way? How can i prevent that?

Comment: It's not changing the values, it's just printing them in scientific notation. The values are the same.

Comment: I guess it's simply because the first element of `my_array[10000]` is way larger than others, not because the index is high. You can try putting `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` before, although I am not sure whether that works always.

Comment: The underlying data isn't changing, it just looks like the shell is printing them in scientific notation. But, they are still the same number: `193.003 == 1.93003000000e+2 # returns True`